# WPF VirtualizingWrapPanel Selected Item Change cause scroll

Tags: wpf, scroll, virtualization, selectionchanged

I have implemented a virtualizing panel that works pretty well, the panel implements IScrollInfo. I am in the process of getting it to work using a keyboard. The Panel is used in a ListView as the ListView.ItemsPanel. When the user presses down the selected item correctly changes but no scrolling occurs and when you reach the last visible item you can not press down any longer. I am trying to figure out how to have the panel aware of the selected item and scroll appropriately. I have tried searching around but I cant seem to find anything related to what I want to do. A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56578152/VirtualizingTilePanel.cs) is the code for the VirtualizingWrapPanel

Comment: Can we see some code for your `Custom Panel`?

Comment: @RohitVats I have added a link to the Panel source.

Comment: I have the same problem now. Any news on it?

Comment: @LonelyPixel I just submitted a solution to my problem. Your implementation may vary so take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that works fairly well, I am not sure if it is the best route to take but it seems to work fine.

In the ArrangeOverride method while looping over the children I do the following.

```
var listViewItem = child as ListViewItem;
if (listViewItem != null)
{
    listViewItem.Selected -= ListViewItemSelected;
    listViewItem.Selected += ListViewItemSelected;
}
```

In MeasureOverride I make a call to CleanUpItems in here we will need to unsubscribe from the selected event.

```
var listViewItem = children[i] as ListViewItem;
if (listViewItem != null)
{
    listViewItem.Selected -= ListViewItemSelected;
}
```

I also added the following three functions.

```
private void ListViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var listViewItem = sender as ListViewItem;
    if(listViewItem == null) return;

    var content = listViewItem.Content as CollectionViewGroup;
    if(content != null) return; //item is a group header dont click

    var items = ItemContainerGenerator as ItemContainerGenerator;
    if(items == null) return;
    BringIndexIntoView(items.IndexFromContainer(listViewItem));
    listViewItem.Focus();
}

protected override void BringIndexIntoView(int index)
{
    var offset = GetOffsetForFirstVisibleIndex(index);
    SetVerticalOffset(offset.Height);
}

private Size GetOffsetForFirstVisibleIndex(int index)
{
    int childrenPerRow = CalculateChildrenPerRow(_extent);
    var actualYOffset = ((index / childrenPerRow) * ChildDimension.Height) - ((ViewportHeight - ChildDimension.Height) / 2);
    if (actualYOffset < 0)
    {
        actualYOffset = 0;
    }
    Size offset = new Size(_offset.X, actualYOffset);
    return offset;
}
```

The GetOffsetForFirstVisibleIndex function will probably vary depending on your implementation but that should be enough info if anyone else is having trouble coming up with a solution.

Comment: When I try that, the selected item is always exactly in the middle of the view. The selection doesn't move up or down until the border and scroll only then, but it always scrolls. Also, Up/PageUp and Down/PageDown always move the selection by a single line. So this doesn't seem to be a good or complete solution to the original problem.

Comment: @LonelyPixel The way it scrolls is just how I decided to implement it. I wanted something a little different, you can make it work however you want by modifying GetOffsetForFirstVisibleIndex. The method simply returns an offset that the view will scroll to. As far as PageUp and PageDown are concerned I had no use for those controls (my users are using a remote so the keys are limited) so I did nothing with their implementation. I simply posted this code so others could see how to hookup the panel to receive notification of the selected item changing.